# clicking any link at the bottom scrollbar "snaps" to the top of page

Tags: javascript, css

i have this annoying problem with my site where, when you click on a dummy link or checkbox at the bottom of the pages, the scrollbar snaps back to the top. i have to scroll down again, to keep clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you are starting with a link to the top of the page (`href="#"`). Don't do that.

Follow the principles of [pragmatic enhancement](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) instead.

Comment: problem is that this happens with all checkboxes as well.

Comment: what should i replace href="#" with ?

Comment: There is no reason this problem should occur with regular checkboxes. You'll have to show example pages for that. The article I linked to explains what to replace # with.